# JQuery After resize image canvas resize only image not a canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

JQuery After resize image canvas resize only image not a canvas

```
function resizeImage(width, height){
    var image = document.getElementById('resizeImage'),
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(image,cropLeft, cropTop, cropWidth, cropHeight,10,10,width,height);

    return canvas;
  };
```

above function resize image but show extra canvas part in return canvas;

How i can get fixed height width resize image using simple jquery html?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function resizeImage(width, height){
    var image = document.getElementById('resizeImage'),
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.canvas.height = height;//pass height
    ctx.canvas.width = width;//pass width
    ctx.drawImage(image,cropLeft, cropTop, cropWidth, cropHeight,10,10,width,height);
    return canvas;
  };
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: cropHeight is not defined

Comment: @jayeshchaudhary you need to pass height and width ther